# What is the easiest way to get the pitchfork in borderlands the pre sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I have played all of the borderlands games and beat them all too. I also like playing Aurelia the baroness in the pre sequel but I cant find the pitchfork. Is there an easier way to get it?

Comment: Define "easy"...

Answer (score 2):

The pitchfork does not have a set enemy that drops it in Borderlands the Pre-Sequel. It can be looted from any lootable source.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Pitchfork)